# ¿Como configurar un proxy a traves de comandos de consola en windows 10?

Tags: python, script, windows10, proxy

Buenas estoy realizando un script con python para poder configurar un proxy para que todos los datos de la red salgan a traves del servidor proxy, el caso es que no se cuales son los comandos de consolas para realizar dicha acción, y por más que he buscado no he encontrado nada a excepción de `netsh` que no a funcionado

Comment: ¿Y tiene que ser por linea de comandos? ¿Exactamente qué necesitas hacer? ¿Tu script de Python levantará un servidor proxy? ¿Cuál?

Comment: Si tiene que ser por linea de comando porque con el script de python uso el os.system para escribir los códigos en la powershell, mi script no levanta un servidor proxy, sería configurar windows para que use un proxy

Answer (score -1):

Aqui en esta nota hablan al respecto, espero te sirva [enlace] (https://rm-rf.es/configurar-windows-update-proxy-netsh-ie-proxycfg/)

Comment: Aunque teoricamente este enlace conteste la pregunta, es preferible que incluyas las partes esenciales del mismo en la respuesta. Los enlaces pueden caducar y desaparecer. Ademas llevar al usuario a que lea en otro lugar la respuesta, no es la mejor opción.